# SQL Server stored procedure called from another stored proc returns command completed succesfully but no result set

Tags: sql-server

I have two stored procedures; I am calling one stored proc from another.

I return a table from the 1st stored procedure. When I execute the 1st alone, I get the table correctly.

But when I call the 1st stored procedure from another stored procedure, it always returns command completed successfully and no results.

I call it like this in stored proc 2:

```
set @query = 'exec servername.dbo.storedproc1 @ClassName = ''' + 
             @ClassName +''', @StatusName = ''' + @StatusName 
exec(@query)
```

Comment: the first stored proc is stored in a server where the linked servers are present and I need to call it from the second stored proc stored in a server where no linked servers present which is in prod .I edited my above correctly as well.

Comment: Try call procedure no like string and then insert resultset in a temporary table.

Comment: Can you explain in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a temporary table that captures data obtained from executing first procedure . Then use Select statement to retrieve desired data from temporary table. Don't forget to use drop the temporary table table  after Select statement else  next time you execute the procedure error will be thrown saying table already exist . On other hand you can use table variable to avoid dropping table as scope of table variable is limited to lifetime of the containing stored procedure.
`

```
Insert into @temptable
Exec sprcdre1

Select * from  @temptable
```

Comment: I have a temp table in the first stored procedure already that's why I said it returns a table ,but i cannot so s simple slect from it as i need to get to the server id and db where its stored in first by getting some params from asp.net

Comment: sure iam trying this already its the same answer as @matan yungman above suggested

Comment: Don.t forget INTO keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the outer procedure, create a temporary table with a similar schema to the result set returned from the inner procedure.
When calling the inner procedure, use insert..exec, like this:

```
insert #tempTable exec InnerProcedure
```

Then select the data from the temporary table.